# Error al publicar proyecto en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

Estoy tratando de publicar mi proyecto, para generar el compilado, lo estoy generando localmente en mi equipo (nada de FTP o IIS), pero siempre me genera el siguiente error:

> La característica "literal predeterminado" no está disponible en C#
>   7.0. Use la versión del lenguaje 7.1 u otra posterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la plataforma de destino tengo la versión de .NET 4.6.1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la version del lenguaje tengo seleccionado C# 7.3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También intente con la primera opción que dice *Versión principal mas reciente de C# (predeterminada)*, pero no se lograr publicar correctamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click derecho en tu proyecto, propiedades, dentro de las propiedades, vas a Build, en Build, seleccionas Advanced, en esa pantalla, seleccionas la primera opción "versión más reciente", de la siguiente manera:

[image: Propiedades de un proyecto de Visual Studio]

[image: Build, configuración avanzada]

Ahora, en caso no resulte, edita el archivo `.pubxml` y le agregas esta línea:

```
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
```

Quedando de esta manera, a modo de ejemplo:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Puedes indicarme en donde encuentro el archivo `.pubxml`

Comment: mira las carpetas que se han creado cuando intentaste darle publicar, en el explorador de soluciones

Comment: Excelente, funciono agregando la linea `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`

Comment: perfecto :D a seguir desarrollando con todo el power 2.0!!!